# SoIve this cipher, please

Tags: cipher

Solve this cipher, please.

24/12 is coming so 25 24 18 25 27 18 25 26 18 27 29 18 26 23 18 26 45 18 26 42 18 26 27 18 25 21 18 23 22 18 26 28 18 27 29 18 26 21 18 25 28 18 24 45 18 23 20 18 26 22 18 25 27 18 24 26 18 27 41 18 24 29 18 25 21 18 23 44 18 23 44 everyone~

Comment: I'm going to bump it since nobody voted.

Comment: Is the oddity in the title deliberate?

Comment: Is this a puzzle of your own devising or does it come from somewhere else?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I just want to avoid "duplicate title" error.

Comment: We need an answer to that question about whether the puzzle comes from somewhere else, and I'm closing it until we have that. (I have a specific reason for thinking that it _might_ come from somewhere else.)

Comment: Just so you're aware, commenting on a question doesn't bump it, only edits do that.

Comment: More to the point, "bumping" is rude and should generally be avoided.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan They won't let you post the answer.

Comment: Who won't let me post the answer?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I found the puzzle on Scratch. I suspect it's copyrighted.

Comment: Ah. If it comes from somewhere else then it needs full attribution, and if it's a copyrighted thing that you don't have permission to post here then it shouldn't be here at all.

Comment: If this question were accepting answers, I'd say that it says rot13(Zreel Puevfgznf!) and that CyberChef practically solves it on its own.

Answer (score 0):

**PARTIAL**

First thing to notice:

> Every third number is '18', which is also the smallest number in the sequence.

Using this information

> I offset the numbers and write them up separatedly: 
>  **7/6 7/9 7/8 9/11 8/5 8/27 8/24 8/9 7/3 5/4 8/10 9/11 8/3 7/10 6/27 5/2 8/4 7/9 6/8 9/23 6/11 7/3 5/26 5/26** 
>  I suspect these might be dates, but I this contradicts with the fact that '24/12' is written in the question (US format vs EN format)

Comment: Oops, I forgot to color some of the numbers.